# RGB to LMS color space conversion with OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, rgb

I have a problem understanding how i correctly use my matrices types for a color conversion from rgb to lms color space with opencv. The paper I've found is [here](http://biecoll.ub.uni-bielefeld.de/volltexte/2007/52/pdf/ICVS2007-6.pdf). What I want to do is simply calculate the lms color triples as following:

```
Mat actRGBVec = new Mat(1,3,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR);
Mat lmsResVec = new Mat(1,3,CvType.CV_64FC3);

lmsMat = new Mat(inputImg.rows(),inputImg.cols(),CvType.CV_64FC3);

// iterate through all pixels and multiply rgb values with the lms transformation matrix
try {
  for (int x = 0; x < inputImg.rows(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < inputImg.cols(); y++) {
      actRGBVal = inputImg.get(x, y);

      // vector holding rgb info
      actRGBVec.put(0, 0, actRGBVal);
      Core.gemm(lmsTransformMat, actRGBVec, 1, null, 0, lmsResVec, 0);

      lmsMat.put(x, y, lmsResVec.get(0, 0));
    }
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {
  Log.d("ImageHandler","Error rgb to lms conversion! " + e.getMessage());
}
```

lmsMat is of type CV_64FC3. inputImg is of type Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR. lmsTransformMat is of type CV_64FC1 (since it contains only scalar values this should be the right type?).

The Exception says: Error rgb to lms conversion! null
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your matrices have the correct dimensions and type:

- `inputImage` can't be of type `Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR`. That's a constant that is used for the `cvtColor` function, not an OpenCV matrix type. Since your input image is probably a color image, that would make the correct type `CV_8UC3`.
- `lmsTransformMat` should be a 3x3 matrix of type `CV_64FC1`.
- `actRGBVec` needs to be 3x1 matrix of the same type as `lmsTransformMat`. (Again: `Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR` is not a matrix type).
- `lmsResVec` needs to be a 3x1 matrix of the same type as `lmsTransformMat`. (You can just use `new Mat()` however. OpenCV will take care of it in `Core.gemm`).
- `lmsMat` looks fine.

In addition you pass `null` as the `src3` parameter to `Core.gemm`. That's the cause of your `NullPointerException`. Since your `beta` parameter is `0` you can just provide `new Mat()` instead of `null`.